# Rails 3 Serving completely static page on Index view with no caching enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, controller

Ive got memcached installed and have it set to be the default cache store to be used. However in development mode its off and my memcached server is not even running yet rails is serving up a completely static index view. I removed caches_page, etc from the controller so everything in the controller is what a normal CRUD controller looks like. I even removed the index action and index view from the rails app yet rails persists to serve the static page. I deleted the /tmp directory, made sure perform_caching was set to false in dev environment and it has no effect. Its only on that one page, everything else works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue a week ago. Check your public folder. And clear your browser's cache.

Comment: yep, it was coming from the public folder.